# How to specify an interface as a generic type argument when using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics, reflection

I am trying to instantiate a type using reflection that takes a contract as a generic type parameter.  If it was a generic type method, I could use the .MakeGenricMethod method, and specify the reflected type.  However, if the type itself is not generic, how would I go about specifying the interface as the contract?

This is what the code would look like with the assemblies loaded normally:

```
Ice.Lib.Framework.WCFServiceSupport.CreateImpl<Erp.Proxy.BO.JobEntryImpl>(EpicorSession, Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase<Erp.Contracts.JobEntrySvcContract>.UriPath);
```

Where I am stuck is at the "Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase" part.

I need to specify that Erp.Contracts.JobEntrySvcContract interface when reflecting or the class won't instantiate properly.  I then need to grab that .UriPath property and plug it into my CreateImpl method.

Here's what I've got for that part:

```
 Type _ImplBase = asmEpicorServiceModel.GetType("Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase");      
            FieldInfo UriPath = _ImplBase.GetField("UriPath", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

The problem is, _ImplBase is returning null, and I think this is because I didn't specify that Interface as the contract so it failed.

```
public class ImplBase<TContract> : ImplBase where TContract : class
{
    public static readonly string UriPath;
```

Eventually, I will need to grab that UriPath static property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Type _ImplBase = Type.GetType("Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase`1[[Erp.Contracts.JobEntrySvcContract, Assembly2]], Assembly1");
```

Assuming that Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase is defined in *Assembly1* and Erp.Contracts.JobEntrySvcContract in *Assembly2*.

Comment: This syntax looks goofy to me...For the Assembly1 and Assembly2 did you want the assembly names as strings or the Assembly object instances?

Comment: @user3386553 Assembly names. I think it's clear since they are part of the string being passed to the Type.GetType method.

Comment: I tried using your code and concatenating the assembly names FullName properties, but it still returns a null reference.

Comment: You may have a typo somewhere. The string you want to use is `typeof(Epicor.ServiceModel.Channels.ImplBase<Erp.Contracts.JobEntrySvcContract>).AssemblyQualifiedName`